Block HTTP/HTTPS POST/PUT from a container
Is there a practical way to inspect HTTP/HTTPS and block arbitrary POST and PUT requests, from within a container, to the internet? (while still allowing GET requests)
I had a look at eBPF but I am not sure how to properly set it up, nor if that is the right tool for this. Or is it easier to use some web-proxy with some sort of ssl bump?
Thank you.

You can't inspect HTTPS traffic because it's encrypted. That's the whole point of HTTPS.

That is clear to me @larsks yet I am ready to accept working with e.g. a proxy, ssl-bump and self-signed certs injected to the client somehow. I can't really control the application inside the container very well, but I can control the container. I don't think it has an easy solution, that is the whole point of asking for help here :)

For plain HTTP traffic this is fairly trivial, you can likely just do it with a cgroup_skb program type which parses HTTP, since the method is always in the first line of a request this is fairly easy to do.
But HTTPS is a whole different beast. You can't look inside of the TLS connection with just a network program. There is a project called eCapture that use uprobes to attach to processes and capture the key exchange, then that key is sent to a userspace program which can use it together with the encrypted traffic to decrypt and look inside. Their purpose is to packet capture the contents of encrypted traffic without having to use a custom cert + private key
So in theory you can adopt that encryption key capturing technique. Instead of capturing the traffic like eCapture you need to be able to intercept it as well. So you would have to redirect the encrypted traffic to the userspace app which would serve as proxy and it would use the encryption key to inspect the traffic and block unwanted traffic.
Note that the encryption key stealing only works for "known" libraries, essentially eCapture just implemented a list of the most common encryption libraries + support for Go applications and may not universally work if someone rolls their own crypto or uses a niche library.

That is pretty cool! Thanks for pointing it out Dylan! I am happy if it works with a regular browser (running inside the container) + regular curl/wget. So I'd basically would have to write my own proxy and make all applications use it, right? and it will have to somehow map what it gets from the capture against the requests that come via proxy, that sounds a bit tricky...

Yes, you can use eBPF to redirect the traffic to your proxy. Directly to the socket its listening on or to a dedicated virtual network device. That way you don't have to do anything to the apps inside the containers. The proxy would have a ringbuffer on which it would recieve new encryption keys. Not sure how eCapture does the association, but its likely based on a connection tuple (src IP, dst IP, src port, dst port). or perhaps session ID. And yes this is very tricky, quite advanced stuff, here be dragons
